# ¿Cómo imprimir el resultado de una función al final?

Tags: c#, funciones

Mi problema es sobre imprimir el resultado de 3 funciones: El promedio de notas, la nota más alta y la más baja, me sale error, cómo hago para mostrar su resultado en las líneas de impresión?

```
class Program
{
    //CREAR ARREGLO GLOBAL
    float[] calificaciones = new float[0];

    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //VARIBALES NECESARIAS
        int cantidad = 0; 
        string valor = "";

        //SE PIDEN LA CANTIDAD DE ALUMNOS
        Console.Write("INGRESE LA CANTIDAD DE ALUMNOS: ");
        valor = Console.ReadLine();
        cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(valor);
        float[] calificaciones = new float[cantidad];
        obtenerNotas(cantidad);
        obtenerPromedio(cantidad);
        notaMinima(cantidad);
        notaMaxima(cantidad);

        //PONER LOS RESULTADOS
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine();                  //DONDE SALE EL ERROR
        Console.WriteLine(notaMaxima(float)); //DONDE SALE EL ERROR
        Console.WriteLine(notaMinima(float)); //DONDE SALE EL ERROR

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

        //CAPTURAR LA INFORMACIÓN DE LAS NOTAS
        public void obtenerNotas (int a)
        {
            int cantidad = a;
            for (int n = 0; n < cantidad ; n++)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("INGRESE LA CALIFICACIÓN DEL ALUMNO NÚMERO " + (n+1) + ": ");
                string valor = Console.ReadLine();
                calificaciones[n] = Convert.ToSingle(valor);
            }
        }

        //ENCONTRAMOS EL PROMEDIO
        public float obtenerPromedio(int b)
        {
            int cantidad = b;
            float suma = 0;
            for (int n = 0; n < cantidad; n++)
            {
                suma += calificaciones[n];
            }

            float promedio = suma / cantidad;
            return promedio;

        }

        //ENCONTRAMOS LA CALIFICACIÓN MÁS BAJA
         public float notaMinima (int c)
        {
            int cantidad = c;
            float minima = 0;
            for (int n = 0; n < cantidad; n++)
            {
                if (calificaciones[n] < minima)
                minima = calificaciones[n];
            }
            return minima;

        }

        //ENCONTRAMOS LA CALIFICACIÓN MÁS ALTA
        public float notaMaxima(int d)
        {
            int cantidad = d;
            float maxima = 0;
            for (int n = 0; n < cantidad; n++)
            {
                if (calificaciones[n] > maxima)
                maxima = calificaciones[n];
            }
            return maxima;
        }

}
```

Comment: +Qué error muestra ? `notaMaxima` recibe un entero y le intenta pasar un nombre de variable que forma parte de las palabras reservadas del lenguaje `float`  es un tipo de dato. quizá debería pasar un array como parámetro

Comment: Me sale Ninguna sobrecarga para el método "Nombre de la función" toma '0' argumentos.

Comment: A simple vista se ve el errror, en notaMaxima y notaMinima le estas pasando float, cuando en realidad le tienes que pasar una variable. Ejmplo: notaMaxima(cantidad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `notaMaxima`  , `notaMinima`  en su código recibe un entero y le intenta pasar un nombre de variable que forma parte de las [palabras reservadas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/) del lenguaje , `float`  es un tipo de dato. quizá debería pasar un `array` como parámetro , ¿quizá `calificaciones` ? pero si su variable es estática no tendría sentido.

En su lugar sugiero mejorar un poco el código evitando este tipo de variables. quizá , debería asignar al `array` de `float` lo que retorne su método `obtenerNotas` para luego si desea obtener el `max` , `min` o `promedio` *(avg)* pueda llamar a esta funciones directamente. además  se utiliza Int32.TryParse para validar la entradas `int` y  `float.TryParse`

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //VARIBALES NECESARIAS
        int cantidad = 0;
        String entrada = "";
        // Para  Asegurar la entrada de un entero
        bool esEntero = false;
        while (!esEntero) // Si no entero volvemos a solicitar la entrada
        {
            //SE PIDEN LA CANTIDAD DE ALUMNOS
            Console.Write("INGRESE LA CANTIDAD DE ALUMNOS: ");
            entrada = Console.ReadLine();
            esEntero = Int32.TryParse(entrada,  out cantidad);
        }


        float[] calificaciones = obtenerNotas(cantidad);

        //MOSTRAR LOS RESULTADOS
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Nota Promedio" + obtenerPromedio(calificaciones));
        Console.WriteLine("Nota máxima " + notaMaxima(calificaciones));
        Console.WriteLine("Nota Minima " + notaMinima(calificaciones));
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    //CAPTURAR LA INFORMACIÓN DE LAS NOTAS
    public static float[] obtenerNotas(int n)
    {
        float[] calificaciones = new float[n];
        string valor = "";
        bool isFloat = false;
        float nota = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            while (!isFloat)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("INGRESE LA CALIFICACIÓN DEL ALUMNO NÚMERO " + (i + 1) + ": ");
                valor = Console.ReadLine();
                // validamos que sea un número flotanto , con punto y no con ,
                isFloat = Single.TryParse(valor, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out nota);

                if (isFloat)
                {
                    calificaciones[i] = nota;
                }

            }
            isFloat = false;
            valor = "";
        }
        return calificaciones;
    }

    //ENCONTRAMOS EL PROMEDIO
    public static float obtenerPromedio(float[] b)
    {
        return b.Average();
    }

    //ENCONTRAMOS LA CALIFICACIÓN MÁS BAJA
    public static float notaMinima(float[] b)
    {
        return b.Min();
    }

    //ENCONTRAMOS LA CALIFICACIÓN MÁS ALTA
    public static float notaMaxima(float[] b)
    {
        return b.Max();
    }
```